# Swift Function return () but Value is something else ans existent

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I make an getData() call to Firebase. I am getting the right Value and I am storing it into a Variable (Ergebnis).
The problem is, that I can't return the Value. I am getting the following error: Unexpected non-void return value in void function' How can I return it from the task?

```swift
func holDaten(Daten: String) async throws -> String{

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let kurstxt = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "aktuellerKurs") as! String
    ref.child("\(kurstxt ?? "default value")/\(Daten ?? "")").getData(completion:  { error, snapshot in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)

            return;
        }
        let Ergebnis = Task{ () -> String in
            do{
                let Ergebnis =  await snapshot?.value as? String ?? "Unknown";
                return Ergebnis
            }
            catch{
                return("Nichts")
                print("Error")
            }
        }

        return Ergebnis
    })
}
```

Comment: You're trying to mix `async` with a function with a completion handler (not using Swift's async/await). See https://wwdcbysundell.com/2021/wrapping-completion-handlers-into-async-apis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to wrap your call to `getData` with [`withCheckedThrowingContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedthrowingcontinuation(function:_:)) like this

```swift
func holDaten(daten: String) async throws -> String {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let kurstxt = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "aktuellerKurs") as! String
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<String, Error>) in
        ref.child("\(kurstxt ?? "default value")/\(daten ?? "")").getData { error, snapshot in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                continuation.resume(with: .failure(error))
                return
            }
            let ergebnis = snapshot?.value as? String ?? "Unknown"
            continuation.resume(with: .success(ergebnis))
        }
    }
}
```